# parcelable class for nameValuePair?

Tags: java, android, basicnamevaluepair

I want to pass `ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs` one activity to another. I wrote `parcelable class` for this.

```
Parcelable Class:

/**Getters/Setters have been removed to make reading easier*//

    public class BasicNameValuePair  implements Parcelable {
        private String name;
        private String value;



     public BasicNameValuePair(String name, String value){
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }

        protected BasicNameValuePair(Parcel in) {
            name = in.readString();
            value = in.readString();
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(name);
            dest.writeString(value);
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        public static final Creator<BasicNameValuePair> CREATOR = new Creator<BasicNameValuePair>() {
            @Override
            public BasicNameValuePair createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new BasicNameValuePair(in);
            }

            @Override
            public BasicNameValuePair[] newArray(int size) {
                return new BasicNameValuePair[size];
            }
        };
    }
```

My first activity that sends data:

```
ArrayList<com.example.ss.myapplication.BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<com.example.ss.myapplication.BasicNameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new com.example.ss.myapplication.BasicNameValuePair("name",value));
        nameValuePairs.add(new com.example.ss.myapplication.BasicNameValuePair("name1", value1));

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("extraextra", nameValuePairs);
                startActivity(intent);
```

In my second activity that get nameValuePair

```
 ArrayList<com.example.ss.myapplication.BasicNameValuePair> testing = this.getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("extraextra");


 for (com.example.ss.myapplication.BasicNameValuePair n : testing) {
            String name = n.getName();
            String value = n.getValue();
            System.out.print("name" + name + "value:" + value);
        }
```

However, I get an error when I want to add data nameValuePairs.

```
BasicNameValuePair(android.os.Parcel) in BasicNameValuePair cannot be applied  to (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
```

How should I change my BasicNameValuePair class?

Comment: create constructor inside BasicNameValuePair

Comment: ` public BasicNameValuePair(String name, String value){
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }`  I created this inside BasicNameValuePair. Now, there is no error, but arraylist cannot pass second activity. @Tauqir

Comment: please update code with new codes

Comment: I updated @Tauqir

Comment: Your code seems fine, have you tried debugging.

Comment: Ah yes, the arraylist pass other activity. But, this seems doesn't work ` System.out.print("name" + name + "value:" + value);` @Tauqir

Comment: do you have getters for those values in `BasicNameValuePair`?

Comment: Yes, I have getters and setters. I didn't write here to make reading easier.  @jibrahim

Comment: do you use auto-generator plugin for parcelable in your android studio?

Comment: How can I cast  `ArrayList<com.example.ss.myapplication.BasicNameValuePair> testing` to ArrayList <org.apache.http.NameValuePair>. @Tauqir @jibrahim

Answer (score 0):

you don't have `getname` and `getvalue` in

```
public class BasicNameValuePair  implements Parcelable {
    private String name;
    private String value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

********************* etc*****************
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have getters and setters. I didn't write here to make reading easier.