# incompatible types: ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, basicnamevaluepair

I asked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472630/parcelable-class-for-namevaluepair). Now I can pass arraylist to another activity.

In my second activity, I am trying to post this arraylist.

```
ArrayList<com.example.ss.myapp.BasicNameValuePair> testing = this.getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("extraextra");

 HttpClient httpclient1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost1 = new HttpPost(url);
                        httppost1.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity((List<? extends org.apache.http.NameValuePair>) testing));
```

I get an error:  `incompatible types: ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> cannot be converted to List<? extends NameValuePair>`

How can I cast `ArrayList<com.example.ss.myapp.BasicNameValuePair> testing` to `ArrayList<NameValuePair> testing`?

Comment: Your code looks good so far, but in order for that cast to be possible, `BasicNameValuePair` must extend `NameValuePair`. Can you double check this?

Comment: Thanks, When I do that, it works. @lulian Popescu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NameValuePair` should be referring to this [link](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/NameValuePair.html). Your class, according to your link, does not extend `NameValuePair`. To achieve that, you need to change your code:

```
 public class BasicNameValuePair extends NameValuePair implements Parcelable {
```

and implement/override all the necessary methods as you wish/is required.